# Azure ML Studio workspace from 3rd party does not show up in workspace list on https://studio.azureml.net/

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have had a few azure ml workspaces though my own Azure account for a while. Recently I was added as "Contributor" to a new Azure workspace as Contributor. In Azure Portal I can see it clearly and have access to it. When going to https://studio.azureml.net/ It does not show up in the list of workspaces of the correct region, nor in any other region.

In Azure Portal I have to change "Directory" (top right account menu) to the 3rd party directory to see it.

Is there a way to do that in azureml.net ? Or is there something else that might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access to the workspace is controlled by the workspace owner from the settings page inside of the Azure ML workspace. the owners/contributors etc. listed in Azure portal does NOT grant you access to the workspace.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!